# How do I bind C-? in bash?

Tags: linux, bash, shell, zsh

I want to bind `C-?` to history-search-backward in bash and/or zsh. I tried the following way

```
bind '"^?": history-search-backward' # bash
bindkey '^?' history-search-backward # zsh
```

The binding works fine, but at the same time `BS` (backspace) stops working correctly. The reason is that `BS` generates the same code as `C-?` what one can check with `C-v BS` and `C-v C-?`. Thus the final result is that both `C-?` and `BS` are bound to history-search-backward what is obviously not what I wanted.

So the question is how can I **properly** bind `C-?` without affecting `BS`?

Comment: I don't think you can do that. If backspace and Ctrl-? send the same code, how will bash tell the difference? Unless you reconfigure your terminal emulator so the backspace key sends BS rather than DEL.

Comment: Is it terminal emulator problem? The same behavior is under console and in zshzle manual we read `Delete is written as '^?'` and later on under _default bindings_ `backward-delete-char (^H ^?)`. Thus it seems to me that this `C-?` (aka `^?`) is somehow hardcoded in shell. But still, there must workaround... there always is! ;)

Comment: There are plenty of workarounds. For example, you can use a shortcut manager in X to map `C-?` to `C-a` and then bind `C-a`. This is not a good solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Which string is sent to the shell when pressing a key or key combination is determined by the terminal.

It seems that a lot (most?) terminal emulators by default send `^?` (ASCII 0x7f, Delete) when pressing the backspace key. While the actual backspace character would be `^H` (ASCII 0x08, Backspace).

If you can change the behaviour of your terminal emulator to send `^H` you should be able to maintain the function of the backspace key while still being able to bind `^?` to something else.

Terminal emulators the provide a GUI for configuration (`gnome-terminal`, `roxterm`, `konsole`, ...) should have an option for that.

Others (`xterm`, `urxvt`, ...) may have appropriate X resources that may be set in `~/.Xdefaults` (or - depending on your distribution - `~/.Xresources`).

For `xterm` you need to set:

```
XTerm.backarrowKeyIsErase: False
```

For `urxvt` set

```
URxvt.backspacekey: ^H
```

please note that this is the actual `^H` (ASCII 0x08) character and not a two character string consisting of `^` and `H`.

To load these settings either call `xrdb -merge ~/.Xdefaults` or close and restart your X session. (The settings will only be enabled for new terminals)

Comment: Indeed, I use terminator (fork of gnome-terminal) and changing ASCII DEL to `^H` did the trick. Thanks!